# Disable keyboard suspend key

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard

How do I disable my keyboard's suspend key? My keyboard (Logitech k800) has a key for powering off the pc, in Ubuntu its working as a suspend button. I've tried assigning another shortcut to that button, but its not preventing the computer from sleeping. Also, I'm not sure if there's a difference between suspend and sleep, but it appears to be turning the computer completely off, but when I start it back up it resumes where it left off.